# Language is not displaying published item in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: publishing

We are trying to publish the item.But the language is not displaying in the popup. The langauge is already there in system/lanaguages. But it is still not displaying.

[image]

Comment: Is there any exception logged in log file?

Comment: No, There is no expectation related to this

Comment: Try this and let us know if it works https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/fix-disappearing-language-error-in-sitecore

Comment: @SumitHelaiya thanks for sharing. Followed the suggestion but finally, Restarted the application then it is working.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you, you can mark the appropriate answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out below to resolve the issue.

**1. Check The Language Definition Config**

Navigate to the App_Config folder `wwwroot\[your site]\App_Config` and look for the `LanguageDefinitions.config`. If it is missing, you will need to reinstall it.

Open up the config file, and search for your language id and region. If you can't find it, reinstall this file.

**2. Restart CM Server**

If the Sitecore items and the config file exist, the last thing to do is `restart CM` and try publishing again.

**Credit:** https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/fix-disappearing-language-error-in-sitecore

Hope it helps!

Comment: If the question is useful can give an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your logged-in user does not have `language:write` permissions for the language `en`. Please check that this permission is set using Security Editor or Access Viewer:

[image: Access Viewer]

This is what happens inside the "Publish Item" dialogue:

- It takes all languages from the context database. Please note that languages are cached so you may need to clear the cache `LanguageProvider - Languages` or restart the server to read new languages from the database.
- If the setting `CheckSecurityOnLanguages` is set to `true` (this is the default value), then for each language, Sitecore will check that the current user has `language:write` permissions. If not, this language will be skipped.
- If there is only one language available, both "Select all" and the language checkboxes will be selected and greyed out like this:

[image: Greyed out language]

Otherwise, all language checkboxes should be selectable.

Comment: i have logged in as admin mode.

Comment: @Rameshkumar have you ever changed the file `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Dialogs\Publish\Publish.xml`? Does it have the element `<Border ID="Languages" />`?

Comment: @Rameshkumar another thing you can try is clearing the cache `LanguageProvider - Languages` if you've just added a new language.

Answer (score 1):

For folks that use Sitecore Managed Cloud or XM Cloud, with less access to server resources than On Prem Sitecore admins, Sitecore recommends [Unprotect the item + save + re-protect the item + save] to refresh dependent resource files.

Much more elegant than restarting the server.

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1003096